# rename multiple files from different directories at once

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have thousands of files in different folders that I would like to rename with their directories and, but less importantly, edit a few details after.

As a structure example:

```
FOLDER A

---> folder 1

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg

---> folder 2

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg

FOLDER B

---> folder 1

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg

...
```

The end name should be: `FOLDER A_folder 1_1.jpg` ...etc

and the less important edit: `FOLDER A - 1_1.jpg` ...etc

I don't know if it's relevant, but I have Ubuntu and from the terminal I've test tried this:

```bash
for file in Folders*/*/*/*.jpg; do
  mv "$file" "${file//\//_}";
done
```

It correctly renames the files with their paths but simultaneously extracts them and put them in the main folder, how do I avoid that?

Comment: What if you have `../FOLDER A/folder 1/folder 1a/{1,2}.jpg`? What is the final form with 2 (or more) subfoders present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the path to the "target" file (the second parameter of the mv command) since you replaced all `/` with `_` practically removing the path and making it part of the new name:

```
for file in FOLDER*/*/*; do
    mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/${file//\//_}";
done
```

**TEST**

Directories and files before running the loop:

```
$ find .
.
./FOLDER B
./FOLDER B/folder 2
./FOLDER B/folder 2/2.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 2/1.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 1
./FOLDER B/folder 1/2.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 1/1.jpg
./FOLDER A
./FOLDER A/folder 2
./FOLDER A/folder 2/2.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 2/1.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 1
./FOLDER A/folder 1/2.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 1/1.jpg
$
```

Renaming the files and the results:

```
$ for file in FOLDER*/*/*; do
>     mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/${file//\//_}";
> done
$ find .
.
./FOLDER B
./FOLDER B/folder 2
./FOLDER B/folder 2/FOLDER B_folder 2_1.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 2/FOLDER B_folder 2_2.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 1
./FOLDER B/folder 1/FOLDER B_folder 1_1.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 1/FOLDER B_folder 1_2.jpg
./FOLDER A
./FOLDER A/folder 2
./FOLDER A/folder 2/FOLDER A_folder 2_1.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 2/FOLDER A_folder 2_2.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 1
./FOLDER A/folder 1/FOLDER A_folder 1_1.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 1/FOLDER A_folder 1_2.jpg
$
```

As for your "less important edit," you can rename the files again, like this:

```
for file in FOLDER*/*/*; do
    mv "$file" "${file//_folder/ -}";
done
```

Note that you don't need to add the path here since the `_folder` to  `-` substitution done to the `file` variable only affects the file name and not the path.

Final result:

```
$ find .
.
./FOLDER B
./FOLDER B/folder 2
./FOLDER B/folder 2/FOLDER B - 2_1.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 2/FOLDER B - 2_2.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 1
./FOLDER B/folder 1/FOLDER B - 1_1.jpg
./FOLDER B/folder 1/FOLDER B - 1_2.jpg
./FOLDER A
./FOLDER A/folder 2
./FOLDER A/folder 2/FOLDER A - 2_1.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 2/FOLDER A - 2_2.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 1
./FOLDER A/folder 1/FOLDER A - 1_1.jpg
./FOLDER A/folder 1/FOLDER A - 1_2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for f1 in `ls`; 
    do for f2 in `ls "$f1"`; 
        do for f3 in `ls $f1/$f2`; 
            do mv "$f1/$f2/$f3" "$f1/$f2/${f1}_${f2}_$f3"; 
        done; 
    done; 
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing it wrong, I get a comparison between my directories:
mv: 'FOLDER A/folder 1/1.jpg' and 'FOLDER A/folder 1/1.jpg' are the same file

Comment: I added a couple of quotation marks, could you try again with them?

Comment: sorry, I still get the same error message, but thank you for helping me

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the braces. It works now!